# How to set focus on the first input OR select with a classname?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have to set the focus on the first element on each tab of a page that have a specific classname.
These elements can be inputs or selects.

> $('form :input:visible:input[class*=validate]:first').focus();

I thought the selector above would do the trick but it only sets the focus on inputs.
How can I change it to include select element ?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(() => {
  $('form :visible[class*=validate]:first').focus();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="validate"/>
</form>
```

You can use just the classnames:

`$('form :visible[class*=validate]:first').focus();`

Comment: Thanks @Anurag Srivastava but the expression produces a syntax error : "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: form :visible:[class*=validate]:first"

Comment: @KMarron Sorry was a typo, there was an extra `:`. Please see attached snippet